# attribute between points to tiles in Google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, tiles, sentinel-2

I have layer of points that are located in Brazil area in very big area.
I would like to get list of the unique tiles of sentienl2 that those points are relate to.
Is something like this possible in GEE?
now I do it manually, using remotepixel and insert the name of the tile manually:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2019-11-01', '2019-11-30')
                  .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'EQUALS','21KXS')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  //.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 100))
                  .select('B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','QA60')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
```

My end goal: to get list based on my points-feature collection of the tiles those points are belong to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have uploaded the Sentinel-2 tiling grid as an asset (KML available for download [here](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products))). Once you have an asset like this, you can do the following:

```
var sentinel2SceneAreas = ee.FeatureCollection('users/wiell/SepalResources/sentinel2SceneAreas')
var sceneAreas = sentinel2SceneAreas.filterBounds(geometry)
  .aggregate_array('name')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8f1cde32b19b4c4d70519e3c277ae57e